# How can I set the proper PATH for actions/checkout?

Tags: github-actions

I have a very simple workflow that uses actions/checkout@v2 with a self-hosted runner (on an Ubuntu 16.04 server).  I want actions/checkout to download submodules, which it can only do with the newer download method.  It always falls back to downloading my repo with the REST API, saying that I need a newer Git in my PATH.  But, git is installed in /usr/bin/, and its version is 2.7.4.  (actions/checkout should only fall back to using the REST API when Git is < 2.18)

I've tried a few things so far, including specifying the PATH with env and set-env.  I've wondered if the issue is caused by git being on a different filesystem than the work directory.  If so, then how can I fix this?  If not, then how can I fix this?

EDIT: I've added the workflow script, with some names changed.

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - branch
jobs:  
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    defaults:
        run:
            shell: bash
            working-directory: release
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        submodules: 'recursive'
      env:
          PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin 
      
    - name: build
      run: |
           fakeroot ./make_actions.sh
      env:
          PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/059/bin/intel64/:/usr/local/gcc-8.3/bin
```

Comment: Can someone please close/delete this question?  I was looking at version numbers wrong, and read "2.18" as "2.1.8".  This somehow eluded me for several days.

Comment: can you please let us know how to specify Git version in PATH?